# Does Hibernate 2nd level cache use just the WHERE clause or the entire query to construct the cache?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, flashback, hibernate-cache

**Scenario:** 
I have a product table with a primary key of product ID. I have set up hibernate with a secondary cache (ehcache) with a read-only strategy and query caching has been enabled.

I have a request to start using [Oracle's flashback features](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS638)

**Question:**
What I would like to know is that, if the product table is archived (using the flashback features) and I am going to use a SQL query as follows, how will that impact the query caching set up in hibernate? Will Hibernate recognise `AS OF` and take the timestamp into account while caching and serving the product entity when queried?:

```
SELECT * FROM product
AS OF TIMESTAMP
TO_TIMESTAMP('2004-04-04 09:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
WHERE productId = '1-XXXX'
```

The question basically is, does Hibernate cache based purely on the `WHERE` clause or does it take the entire query into account when it checks the cache?